# How do you debug an assembly loaded through Assembly.Load(byte[])?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am creating a plugin for a product that loads plugin DLLs using `Assembly.Load(byte[])`. This is all very well and good, but it means that I have no conventional means of loading the debugging symbols to step through my code.

The crazy thing is, several months ago I was having the exact same issue and solved it - and boy was I proud of myself! So I know it can be done, I've just forgotten how!

I have a few vague memories of things I might have tried, but I can't tease the details out of my head:

- .NET Reflector

  - Probably wrong though because I distinctly remember stepping through the original  .cs file
- Using IIS Express rather than Cassini

  - But this strikes me as a weird solution - the assembly is loaded from a byte-array, so the framework knows nothing about where the DLL came from or what an appropriate PDB might look like if it saw one. This problem should exist in any environment.
- Loading the symbols manually through the "Modules" window

  - Tried this; I get "The symbol file xxxxx.pdb does not match the module" - because, of course, we're loading from a byte-array, not the DLL itself.

Comment: You probably used the Load(byte[], byte[]) overload.

Comment: I'd love to be able to do that, but the product is closed-source. I know `Assemly.Load(byte[])` is being used because I used Reflector. I *could* ask them to use `byte[], byte[]` and check for a .pdb file, but then I'd have to wait who knows how long for the next release (supposing it gets approved at all). Thanks though :)

Comment: Is your assembly strongly named?

Comment: Strong naming sounds like a great solution, which I might look into later. Is it hard to do? In the mean time I've done something messy, but it works. The framework only calls one method dynamically (which is the bit I need to debug) so I simply made the dynamically instanciated class a wrapper on the "real" class that does the leg work. I load the "real" class through Assembly.Load(byte[], byte[]) and hey presto. When I'm done with it, I'll just unwrap it. Dirty, but it works.

Comment: @IainFraser Strong naming is easy. You use the strong name tool (sn.exe) to generate a key file. Then in your project properties "Signing" section you can tell the build to sign the assembly using your key file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4fa028b(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your assembly is strongly named, you can put the assembly in the GAC. Strongly named assemblies are **always** loaded from the GAC, even if it is loaded via `Assembly.Load(byte[])`. Then just put your in symbols in `C:\Windows\symbols\dll` or where ever is convenient. I do this all the time to debug our own product's plugin DLLs which are loaded by another application in a similar manner.

You can use `gacutil` to install it in the GAC. Remember to remove it when you're done debugging or you might end up running tests against an old version you GAC'd and forgot about.