# TargetInvocationException.InnerException missing line numbers

Tags: c#

I'm executing some code from dynamically loaded assembly using `Invoke`. Out of curiosity I've thrown an exception in the method I invoke. It works and I can read the exception but it's missing line numbers.

```
var assemblyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(scriptPath);
// I'm using this overload to avoid blocking the dll.
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes); // allows to pass pdb bytes in the second argument.

var myMethod = ...

try
{
    myMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException); // missing line numbers
}
```

Dynamically loaded assembly was built in debug mode.

Any idea why that happens, and how can I get it to show line numbers?

In this case I'm using .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Are the pdb's present?

Comment: @Silvermind yes I have pdb but I'm not sure it's loaded. It's not in the folder where dll gets loaded from but it's in my output folder.

Comment: @Silvermind I'm using `Assembly.Load` with bytes passed the second argument allows to pass pdb.. I can try that

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004580/how-do-you-debug-an-assembly-loaded-through-assembly-loadbyte

Comment: Using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and other overloads cause the same problem...

Comment: passing pdb bytes to `Assembly.Load` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passing pdb bytes to Assembly.Load worked